# Resolving user-defined class name conflict with built-in class name

Tags: typescript, import, namespaces

I'm defining and implementing a `Map` class in TypeScript which also uses the built-in `Map` class (with generics). Obviously the names clash. Can I somehow import the built-in `Map` using explicit namespace (like one would do in Java) or is there a different way to resolve a conflict like this?

```js
export class Map // my map
{
    private readonly items: Map<string, string>; // built-in map
}
```

I've looked through the TS core [definition files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L111) but can't figure out if they use any namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question myself so I might as well provide a response after quite a bit of time wasted trying to find an answer myself.

In modern browsers, the global namespace can be accessed via the global variable '[globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)' (e.g. `globalThis.Map`).

You'll need a polyfill to get this working in old browsers such as EdgeHTML.